# combining similar click handlers in order to reduce code being used in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 click events that go through a series of different actions, the only thing that is different between the 2 events though is 2 lines. Is there a way of combining these clicks in order to cut down the amount of code being used?

```
$('a.register').click(function() {
                $('h4#registerHead').addClass('active');
                $('#registerMessage').show();
                $('#nav li span a').css({'color':'#8F8F8F'});
                $('#alertNav').css({'color':'#dedede'}).addClass('activeSub');
            });

            $('a.subscribe').click(function() {
                $('h4#subscribeHead').addClass('active');
                $('#subscribeMessage').show();
                $('#nav li span a').css({'color':'#8F8F8F'});
                $('#alertNav').css({'color':'#dedede'}).addClass('activeSub');
            });
```

All advice welcome on this, and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way:

```
var doIt = function(event){
  $("h4#"+event.data.type+"Head").addClass('active');
  $("#"+event.data.type+"Message").show();
  $('#nav li span a').css({'color':'#8F8F8F'});
  $('#alertNav').css({'color':'#dedede'}).addClass('activeSub');
};

$('a.register').bind('click', {type: 'register'}, doIt);
$('a.subscribe').bind('click', {type: 'subscribe', doIt});
```

Second way:

```
var commonHandler = function(){
  $('#nav li span a').css({'color':'#8F8F8F'});
  $('#alertNav').css({'color':'#dedede'}).addClass('activeSub');
};

$('a.register').click(function() {
  $('h4#registerHead').addClass('active');
  $('#registerMessage').show();
  commonHandler();
});

$('a.subscribe').click(function() {
  $('h4#subscribeHead').addClass('active');
  $('#subscribeMessage').show();
  commonHandler();
});
```

Comment: I'd go with the first way. Its very clear at the point of binding.

Comment: This way may be difficult for newcomers :) Especially if we will use on() instead of click() and bind(). :)

Comment: I believe the close brace in the first way should be after 'subscribe' not doIt.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it so that it depends on the structure of the document and the relative positioning of the elements within it.  Obviously, this depends on your HTML.  The following assumes that each link is contained within a DIV, that contains the non-common elements as well.  Adapt it to your HTML, which may involve modifying the HTML to make it easier, as needed.

```
$('a.register, a.subscribe').click( function() {
     var $container = $(this).closest('div.container');
     $('h4',$container).addClass('active');
     $('.message',$container).show();
     $('#nav li span a').css({'color':'#8F8F8F'}); 
     $('#alertNav').css({'color':'#dedede'}).addClass('activeSub');
});
```

Example HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <h4>Register</h4>
   <div id="registerMessage" class="message"></div>
   <div>
      <a href="#" class="register">Do it!</a>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <h4>Subscribe</h4>
   <div id="subscribeMessage" class="message"></div>
   <div>
      <a href="#" class="subscribe">Do it!</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice technique if the html permits

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing that function is very simple.  This would be the easiest approach as I see it

```
function generateClickHandler(type) {
  return function() {
    $('h4#' + type + 'Head').addClass('active');
    $('#' + type + 'Message').show();
    $('#nav li span a').css({'color':'#8F8F8F'});
    $('#alertNav').css({'color':'#dedede'}).addClass('activeSub');
  };
}

$('a.register').click(generateClickHandler('register'));
$('a.subscribe').click(generateClickHandler('subscribe'));
```

Comment: You need to wrap those in anonymous functions otherwise they're going to get executed when the handers are set up -- or the function needs to return another function.